# Atomic and molecular orbital

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory

I have read in my book that ,energy of atomic orbital is greater than that of molecular orbital . I know the fact that lower energy corresponds to higher stability .

But I can't figure out the reason of why does atomic orbital possess higher energy ?

Comment: See Linear Combination Of atomic Orbitals